# Replace values in multiple columns based on condition of other columns

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| V1_res | V1_det | V2_res | V2_det | V3_res | V3_det |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | N | 0.4 | Y | 0.4 | N |
| 0.3 | N | 0.5 | Y | 0.3 | Y |
| 0.5 | Y | 0.1 | N | 0.2 | N |

I want to replace all the values in the `_res` columns with `NA` if the corresponding row in the `_det` column is "N"

My real dataset has much more than 3 columns so I want to avoid doing it like below, one at a time for each column. I would like a way to replace all values at once, preferably using tidyverse.

`df %>% mutate(V1_res = case_when(V1_det == 'N' ~ NA))`

Comment: You find answers herre I guess https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot to long, use `replace`, and then pivot back to wide:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_sep = "_", names_to = c("var", ".value")) |> 
  mutate(res = replace(res, det == "N", NA),
         id = cumsum(var == "V1")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "var", values_from = c("res", "det"), 
              names_glue = "{var}_{.value}", names_vary = "slowest") |> 
  select(-id)

#   V1_res V1_det V2_res V2_det V3_res V3_det
# 1     NA      N    0.4      Y     NA      N
# 2     NA      N    0.5      Y    0.3      Y
# 3    0.5      Y     NA      N     NA      N
```

Here's another solution with `dplyover::across2`:

```r
library(dplyover)
df |> 
  mutate(across2(ends_with("res"), ends_with("det"),
                 ~ replace(.x, .y == "N", NA), .names = "{xcol}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively with `purrr map` functions

```r
# get the names of columns that ends with res
res <- names(data)[which(endsWith(names(data),'res'))]

# get the names of columns that ends with det
det <- names(data)[which(endsWith(names(data),'det'))]

data_res <- purrr::map2_dfc(data[, res], data[,det], ~ ifelse(.y=='N',NA,.x) )

data <- cbind(data_res, data[,det])

# output

  V1_res V2_res V3_res V1_det V2_det V3_det
1     NA    0.4     NA      N      Y      N
2     NA    0.5    0.3      N      Y      Y
3    0.5     NA     NA      Y      N      N
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, `d` being your dataframe:

```
gsub('_.*$', '', names(d)) |>
  unique() |>
  Map(f = \(prefix){res_var = paste0(prefix, '_res')
                    det_var = paste0(prefix, '_det')
                    cbind(d[res_var] * c(1, NA)[1 + (d[det_var] == 'N')],
                          d[det_var]
                         )
                   }
  ) |>
  Reduce(f = cbind)
```

```
##   V1_res V1_det V2_res V2_det V3_res V3_det
## 1     NA      N    0.4      Y     NA      N
## 2     NA      N    0.5      Y    0.3      Y
## 3    0.5      Y     NA      N     NA      N
```

This variant uses the unique variable prefixes (`V1_` etc) to match *res*ult and *det*ection(?) flags of a given variable, does the necessary replacements for each pair and finally `cbind`s the pairs again.